# Batch entity creation in axon

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

Disclaimer: I'm completely new to Event Sourcing, Axon Framework and DDD, so there is quite big possibility I'm doing something wrong.

I'm doing an application to manage events - conferences, workshops etc.

I have one aggregate root, which is EventProposal. There should be a possibility to assign a TodoList to given EventProposal. TodoList is another aggregate root, consisting of TodoItems - entities. TodoItem can be edited, mark as done etc.

There is a requirement of assigning TodoItem to TodoList, which I've implemented this way:

```
public class TodoList extends AbstractAnnotatedAggregateRoot {
    @AggregateIdentifier
    private TodoListId id;

    @EventSourcedMember
    private List<TodoItem> todoItems = Lists.newArrayList();

    ...

    public void assignTodoItem(TodoItemId todoItemId, String content, LocalDate creationDate) {

        if (alreadyHasTodoItemWith(todoItemId)) {
            apply(new TodoItemNotAssignedToTodoList(
                            id, todoItemId)
            );

            return;
        }

        apply(new TodoItemAssignedToTodoListEvent(
                        id, todoItemId, content, creationDate)
        );
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(TodoItemAssignedToTodoListEvent event) {
        final TodoItem item = TodoItemFactory.create(
                event.todoItemId(),
                event.description(),
                event.createdAt()
        );

        todoItems.add(item);
    }
```

Corresponding success-path command and event:

```
@Value
@Accessors(fluent = true)
public class AssignTodoItemToTodoListCommand {

    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    private final TodoListId todoListId;
    private final TodoItemId todoItemId;
    private final String description;
    private final LocalDate createdAt;

}



@Value
@Accessors(fluent = true)
public class TodoItemAssignedToTodoListEvent {

    private final TodoListId todoListId;
    private final TodoItemId todoItemId;
    private final String description;
    private final LocalDate createdAt;

}
```

This could be easly tested with Axon's BDD-way. (GivenThenFixture)

But now - there is another requirement: one should be able to create TodoList upon existing TodoListTemplate. Template is just an aggregate that wrapps a collection of TodoItemTemplates.

And there comes my implementation problem. I tried something like (in TodoList class):

```
public void fulfillWith(TodoListTemplate todoListTemplate, LocalDate creationDate) {
    if (alreadyHasAnyTodoItem()) {
        apply(new TodoListNotFulfilledWithTemplateEvent(
                        id,
                        todoListTemplate.id()
                )
        );
        return;
    }

    apply(new TodoListFulfilledWithTemplateEvent(
                    id,
                    todoListTemplate.id(),
                    todoListTemplate.todoItemDescriptions(),
                    creationDate
            )
    );
}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(TodoListFulfilledWithTemplateEvent event) {
    todoItems.addAll(
        fromDescriptions(event.todoItemDescriptions(), event.fulfilledAt())
    );
}

private Collection<TodoItem> fromDescriptions(Collection<String> descriptions, LocalDate creationDate) {
    return descriptions.stream()
            .map(description -> TodoItemFactory.create(description, creationDate))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Again, commands and events:

```
@Value
@Accessors(fluent = true)
public class FulfillTodoListWithTemplateCommand {

    private final TodoListId todoListId;
    private final TodoListTemplateId todoListTemplateId;
    private final LocalDate creationDate;

}

@Value
@Accessors(fluent = true)
public class TodoListFulfilledWithTemplateEvent {

    private final TodoListId todoListId;
    private final TodoListTemplateId todoListTemplateId;
    private final List<String> todoItemDescriptions;
    private final LocalDate fulfilledAt;
}
```

Problem:
As you can see - there is `TodoItemFactory` class involved, generating an unique ID:

```
public static TodoItem create(String content, LocalDate createdAt) {
        return TodoItemFactory.create(nextId(), content, createdAt);
}
```

This way it can't be tested with axon - it gives me error `org.axonframework.test.AxonAssertionError: Illegal state change detected!` 
This is quite obvious - working aggregate's ID is different than the one's constructed after aplying events.

Finally, my question arrives:

**How should I solve this?**

- Generate those IDs somewhere and include them in outcoming TodoListFulfilledWithTemplateEvent? This leads to having two collections in an event - one for IDs, one for item contents/descriptions.
- Assume that I got those IDs generated before and include them not only in outcoming Event, but also in incoming Command. This leads to same ugliness as before, but twice.
- Do it in the way that I invoke 'assingTodoItemToTodoList' method multiple times, which will generate a lot of events and could produce reordering as events are async.

Sorry for verboseness, I tried to be as specific as possible.

Comment: I'd question whether event sourcing is appropriate for this problem domain.  It sounds like you're just doing regular CRUD, so I'm not sure that DDD is even appropriate let alone CQRS/Event Sourcing.  That is, I don't see any actual domain-specific behavior in any of the code above.

Comment: @JoshKodroff sounds like slnowak was trying to attempt a solution for http://todobackend.com. CQRS and DDD aren't a good fit for the use-case however the idea is to get different implementations for the same problem statement for comparison. There exists (now) a Axon solution to this problem. https://github.com/ryanoglesby08/todo-backend-axon